# Passing JSON object from client to server

Tags: c#, javascript, json, jquery, webmethod

I am having trouble making a client site AJAX call and then passing the JSON object response to server side using PageMethods to do some conditional logic

The JSON response received back from the  web service is:

```
{"Status":"Internal"}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GoRedirect._Default" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function invokeService() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: "false",
                    url: "http://Domain.Local/InternalCheck/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(result);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
        }
        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            var objJSON = result.Status;
            PageMethods.GetJSONResponse(objJSON);
        }
        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
        invokeService();
    </script>
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace GoRedirect
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ServerJSON
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetJSONResponse(string objJson)
    {
        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string JSONResponse = serializer.Serialize(objJson);
            return JSONResponse;
        }
        catch(Exception errorException)
        {
            return errorException.ToString();
        }

    }

    public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        If (JSONResponse.Status == "Internal")
        {
        //Do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the problem you are having? For instance, JSON doesn't normally allow 'get' requests'. Try using a POST and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post from Dave Ward : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

It looks like you would need to use POST instead of GET, as Vincent said, as well as an empty data parameter and content type:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: "false",
                    url: "http://Domain.Local/InternalCheck/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(result);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
```